# Zend Date returning wrong value

Tags: php, zend-framework

Zend date is subtracting a year from the date at the end of the year. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
$fromDate = '2022-01-01 05:00:00';

echo $fromDate . "\n";
> 2022-01-01 05:00:00
$fromDateObj = new Zend_Date($fromDate,Zend_Date::ISO_8601);
$fromDateObj->setTimezone('Europe/London');
$from = $fromDateObj->toString('Y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
echo $from . "\n";
> 2021-01-01 05:00:00
```

Thanks

Comment: Which version of zend are you using? I just tried your code under [zendframework-1.12.20](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/tree/release-1.12.20), and I get the correct result (`2022-01-01 05:00:00`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Y" is the iso year. One should use "y-MM.." for this.